# Calling methods for generic types

Tags: java

I am new to Java. Please help me with this code.

I am creating a utility class with generic parameter. In the API of utility class, I called some API of generic type.

I am assuming that the user of this class will pass only that generic which has this API (getInt in my case) implemented.

```
public class Utility <DataType> {

   private DataType d;

   public Utility (DataType d_)
   {
       d = d_;
   }

   public int getValue ()
   {
      return d.getInt();
   }
}
```

Please point me what I am doing wrong here.

Compilation error in d.getInt(). Cannot resolve getInt method.

I added the abstract interface:

```
abstract interface DataType {
  public int getInt();
}
```

Still it is erroring out.

Comment: Do you have a `getInt()` method in `DataType`?

Comment: Currently there is no DataType class. As it is generic, user will define it in its code. This utility class is in library.

Comment: if there is not method yet, and you want the user to implement it in his code, this create `DataType` as interface, then the user should implement it, otherwise the compiler will keeps complain

Comment: How can the compiler knows that `DataType` will have a `getInt()` method? You need to use an Interface.

Comment: i edited my post. After adding interface as well, I am getting the error.

Comment: This is probably since you are referencing another DataType not your class check what you have imported import com.sun.prism.PixelFormat.DataType;?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot simply promise your compiler that a method will exist in all derived classes. You must make it exist. You have to define it. Use inheritance or an interface to accomplish that.

**Option 1. Inheritance**

Define an abstract base class with an abstract method `getInt()`. All non-abstract children must then implement `getInt()`.

```
public abstract class DataType() {
    public abstract int getInt();
}
```

Children of this class would look like this:

```
public class MyDataType() extends DataType {
    public int getInt() {
       return 3;
    }
}
```

**Option 2. Interface**

Define an interface with a method `getInt()`. All classes implementing that interface must then define a method `getInt()`. By the way, interface names are generally adjectives.

```
public interface DataTypeable {
    public int getInt();
}
```

An implementation of this interface would look like this:

```
public class MyDataType() implements DataTypeable {
    public int getInt() {
       return 5;
    }
}
```

Now your `Utility` class can use the base class or interface like this (replace `DataType` with `DataTypeable` if you go the interface route:

```
public class Utility {

    private DataType d;

    public Utility(DataType d) {
        this.d = d;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return d.getInt();
    }
}
```

**Option 3. Generics plus one of the other options**

For the sake of actually answering the question, here's how to force it to work using generics.

```
public class Utility <T extends DataType> { // or <T implements DataTypeable>

    private T d;

    public Utility(T d) {
        this.d = d;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return d.getInt();
    }
}
```

However, in this case `DataType` must be one of the other options mentioned above. There is really no point in using generics here.

Answer (score 2):

This might be what you are looking for:

Instead of `Utility<DataType>`, you need a type placeholder. Replace it with  `Utility<T>` and replace all `DataType` to `T`.

```
public class Utility <T extends DataType> {

   private T d;

   public Utility (T d_)
   {
       d = d_;
   }

   public T getValue ()
   {
      return d;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As my understanding, you would like to use the DataType as a generic object. So I don't think you have to create interface DataType. Just need to getValue the DataType like the code below:

```
public class Utility<DataType> {

    private DataType d;

    public Utility (DataType d_)
    {
        d = d_;
    }

    public DataType getValue ()
    {
        return d;
    }
}
```

Hope this help!